# spec 2006 benchmark programs in gem5 simulator

Tags: architecture, gem5

I want to run spec benchmark programs(2006/2017) in gem5.
Could anyone please tell me the minimum system requirement for this.
I can not run this on my desktop machine(64 bit, ubuntu-14.04,8 GB RAM, intel core i3).

Thanks in advance.
Moumita

Comment: Why can't you run spec? it's not heavy. Anyway, do you want to run FS (full system) or SE (system emulation) mode?

Comment: How long did you leave it running for? Have you managed to run other programs in gem5 previously to compare what's happening?